# Cannot implicitly convert Dictionary List<string> type parameter to ICollection<string>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics, types

When I try and compile the following code:

```cs
Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> foo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I get:

```
CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>>'
```

Why do I get this error when `List<string>` implements `ICollection<string>`?

Comment: The *dictionary* types are different. Just because one of the two parameters has an inheritance relation with one of the other type's parameters doesn't imply there's any such relation between the dictionaries.

Comment: The inheritance relation affects the dictionary values. You can add a `List<string>` to  `foo` because it accepts anything that implements `ICollection<string>`. This `foo["a"]=new List<string>{"a"};` works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just think about it for a minute:

```
Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> foo
```

This is a dictionary of `string` and `ICollection<string>`. You could for example add a pair of `string`and `HashSet<string>` as that implements `ICollection<string>`.

```
= new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Whoa... now you would add that HashSet to a Dictionary of string and List? How would that work? A HashSet is *not* a List. Well, it won't work. That's why you get errors.

---

Maybe a better example. Assume both `Wolf` and `Sheep` implement `IAnimal`.

```
Dictionary<string, IAnimal> animals = new Dictionary<string, Sheep>();

animals.Add("wolf", new Wolf());
```

What happened to your `Dictionary<string, Sheep>`? There would be a `Wolf` in there now! That cannot be. That's why it does not work.

Comment: If you have an ICollection<IAnimal> you can add Wolf and Sheep objects fine because when you pull them out you're limited to using them as an IAnimal, which they both implement. I don't understand why Dictionary is different.